# Toggle Comment Boxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a site that uses php to populates a series of divs with messages from a MySql server.

I am trying to code in a toggle of each of the messages, so that they can be easily collapsed. The issue lies in how to code it in. Observe:

```
<style type="text/css">
            #slide {

                    }
            #slide-body{   
                height: 100px;
                overflow: hidden;
                transition:             height 10ms ease;
                    -moz-transition:    height 10ms ease;
                    -ms-transition:     height 10ms ease;
                    -o-transition:      height 10ms ease;
                    -webkit-transition: height 10ms ease;
                        }
            .collapsed {
                height: 0px !important;

                        }
            #less {    
                cursor: pointer;
                text-align: left;
                font-style: italic;
                    }
        </style>        
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
                window.onload=function(){
                document.getElementById( 'slide' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                    var body = document.getElementById( 'slide-body' );
                    if( body.className == 'collapsed' ) {
                        body.className = '';
                document.getElementById( 'less' ).textContent = " [-]";
                } else {
                    body.className = 'collapsed';
                document.getElementById( 'less' ).textContent = " [+]  The comment is now hidden. Press [+] to expand.";
                };
                } );
                }//]]>  
            </script>


<div id="slide">
  <div id="less">[-]</div>
  <div id="slide-body">
     Its a piece of cake to bake a pretty cake. Its a piece of cake to bake a pretty cake.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="slide"> 
  <div id="less">[-]</div>
  <div id="slide-body">
     Its a piece of cake to bake a pretty cake. Its a piece of cake to bake a pretty cake.
  </div>   
</div>
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice that you could give me. I have tried using by class instead of Id, but nothing happens at all with that. I am fairly new to using javascript.

Comment: Whats the issue then ?

Comment: First off switch those ID's to classes--ID's must be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an [**example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tnsagyrj/)

I changed the html to use classes instead of ids:

```
<div class="slide">
  <a href="#" class="less">[-]</a>
  <div class="slide-body">
     Its a piece of cake to bake a pretty cake. Its a piece of cake to bake a pretty cake.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide"> 
  <a  href="#" class="less">[-]</a>
  <div class="slide-body">
     Its a piece of cake to bake a pretty cake. Its a piece of cake to bake a pretty cake.
  </div>   
</div>
```

and added this jquery script:

```
$('.less').click(function(e){
    var sbody = $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.slide-body');
    sbody.toggle();  
    $(this).text(sbody.is(':visible') ? '[-]' : '[+]')
})
```

HTH,

-Ted